# Why java.Math.BigInteger bugs out after a certain limit?

Tags: java, biginteger

Am trying to print the sum of digits in 2^n for n = 1 to 1000.
Here's what I've done.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1000;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        BigInteger power = BigInteger.valueOf((int)Math.pow(2, i));
        int sum = 0;
        while (power.intValue() > 0) {
            sum += power.intValue() % 10;
            power = power.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(10));
        }
        System.out.print(sum + "  ");
    }
}
```

It works only till about 2^30 or so and then prints the same result, 46, for the rest.

I tried a similar thing using "long long" in C and that printed 0's after a similar limit.

According to the answers, I changed

```
BigInteger power = BigInteger.valueOf((int)Math.pow(2, i));
```

to

```
BigInteger power = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(i);
```

and 46 changed to 0. Just like C.
Still not working...

Comment: 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^1000 = (2^1001 - 1) / (2 - 1) - 2^0 = 2^1001 - 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `Math.pow` to generate the value you should use the `BigInteger` functions to do so instead.

The sum should be stored in a BigInteger as well not an int.

Comment: I changed

BigInteger power = BigInteger.valueOf((int)Math.pow(2, i));
to
BigInteger power = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(i);

Still not working...       See the edited ques

Comment: @BlueFlame: Are you still using `power.intValue() % 10`?  Because that, too, is not what you want.  You could use `power.mod(BigInteger.TEN).intValue()`, though.  You shouldn't be using `intValue()` unless you already know the `BigInteger` will fit into an `int`...such as when you know it's between `0` and `9`.

Comment: @BlueFlame You mean `for` loop?

Answer (score 7):

You are doing integer arithmetic and then putting it into a biginteger. Use a biginteger's pow method instead.

Answer (score 4):

Because you aren't using `BigInteger`.

Computing numbers using `BigInteger` doesn't let you magically store their sum in an `int`.

Similarly, passing an `int` to `BigInteger.valueOf()` doesn't magically make that `int` bigger.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `Math.pow()` with regular integers, not BigIntegers. You're calling it on integer literals.

You want this:

```
int i = 7; //or whatever power
BigInteger k = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
k = k.pow(i);
```